# Redirecting a | (pipe) or %7C in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

How do I correctly redirect this url permanently,

https://example.com/%7Chttps://example.com/

to,

https://example.com

in htaccess?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Redirect 301 <src_url> <dst_url>
```

So, in your case:

```
Redirect 301 /|example.com example.com
```

Comment: I figured it out. I tried your method and still got a 404. I then tried this and it worked. Redirect 301 /|https://example.com/ https://example.com thanks for sending me in the right direction.